# Why isn't this javascript redirecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I want to have the user click on a button and redirect him/her to a different site I have used the window.location before but for some reason it's not working this time. I'm sure the selector is correct as if I change `window.location` to `alert` it alerts every time, so I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$('#show').click(function(){
        if($('select[name="customers"]').val() == '')
            window.location.replace = 'http://google.com/';
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use either

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com"); // This is like http redirect
```

or

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com"; // This is like a link
```

You **can't** do `window.location.replace= "http://google.com";`

Answer (score 1):

its a method, not a property.

```
window.location.replace('http://google.com/');
```

Comment: window.location.replace emulates a click while window.location.replace() emulates an http response, as far as I know. I could be very wrong of course

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `windows.location.href = ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Set just `window.location.href`. Like this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com/';
```

Comment: `window.location` without `.href` will not work in versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

try: `window.location = 'http://google.com'`